# Remove Tailwind className from component in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, storybook

I have a mobile sidebar component that should be hidden on desktop. Since it's for mobile only mobile it has the className `md:hidden`.

I'm adding all my components to React Storybook to make a library of each component.  But since it has that class of `md:hidden` it doesn't show up unless you change the viewport or the window size.  Is there a way in Storybook to overwrite or take out that className?

I would like it to show up in storybook though, so I was wondering how to either remove or override that class only in storybook.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it backwards (Assuming you set the md:hidden intended for mobile). In tailwind, we use md (min-width:768) if we want the effect to apply when it exceeds 768px (not what we want if we want it to show in desktop view)

So right now, you are hiding your sidebar when it is in desktop view. Try replacing your properties with **hidden md:visible**. In this manner, it would default to hidden (when it's in mobile view) and once it reaches & exceeds the min-width of 768 (desktop view) it will show the sidebar. Hope this would help brother.

Comment: I want it to be hidden on desktop normally, and visible on mobile.  The problem is that I want to show my components individually on react Storybook, and they are invisible there.  I'd like to override the class only in storybook if thats possible.

Comment: Oh sorry i misunderstood. Try to add a boolean prop to your component named isInStoryBook. Then, in your component classname refactor it to something like this:                       className={`'${isInStoryBook ? 'null' : 'md:hidden'}'`} (replace the outer single quotes with template literals ``). So when you are using your component in something else, you could just <Sidebar isInStoryBook={false}>, this would show what you want originally for mobile & On the other hand when you are in StoryBook, you could <Sidebar isInStoryBook={true}>

Comment: Template Literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals